# Siesta generate screenshot on fail

Tags: siesta

I'm running tests using Siesta from command line.

Is that possible to generate screenshots on each test fail while running Siesta test runner?

Edit:
Need to wait for the feature
http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/changelog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in current version 2.0.8, but they are planning to add this in future.
More info can be found on their forum http://www.bryntum.com/forum/

Also Siesta can be runned in cloud on http://www.browserstack.com/ or https://saucelabs.com/. These services offers evene whole screencasts of the tests.